# What would make a Hemomancer only capable of controlling his own blood?

Tags: magic, creature-design, vampires

In the book that I am currently writing, all vampires have this kind of "control" over their own blood using magic. Only vampires who are extremely experienced in magic can interact with the blood of other creatures, but if the creature itself is another vampire, the task is way more difficult.

Comment: Thanks to Lemming, VLAZ, and the-square-cube-law, I wish I could give three "correct answer" marks, they're all great!

Comment: Jus FYI: while I'm pleased as punch that you found their answers helpful, it is considered to be poor form to award the coveted green checkmark within the first 24 to 48 hours after asking a query. Rightly or wrongly, it signals to others that further answers won't be needed (or considered). Especially since they came up with all these great answers based on a question that doesn't really explain what "control" or "controlling own blood" entails.

Comment: Oh, thank you for clarifying, I have removed the checkmark, in regards to the "blood control", the Hemomancer title was there for reference.

Comment: Um. I mean, a hemomancer is someone who magics with blood. A blood mage. That's why I asked for clarification as to "control"! Or do you really mean something else entirely??

Comment: No, that's exactly it, the question was about the reasoning for difficulties while interacting with the blood of other beings, I had this "Interacting with the blood of other creatures is complicated because they don't know its properties" kind of thing, but I didn't know how to elaborate the answer, it didn't feel right to just write it like that lol.

Comment: I guess that's how you would write it! What I'm getting at here is that the question seems to be a bit open ended: there are dozens of potential avenues that a respondent could peruse. Allohemomancy might be difficult for biological reasons (incompatible genetic structures or proteins); it could be difficult as a matter of geography (lack of opportunity to learn and experiment); it could be a matter of immagure cognitive ability (too young = unable to control or even start up the magic); it could be a matter of spiritual development (too wise or mature means loss of ability).

Comment: This is why it's always best to specify as much as possible (without writing a whole book on hemomancy!) within your query! Some discussion of what hemomancy is in context, how it's learned, how its done, what obstacles exist. That kind of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Instinctual familiarity

The hemomancers have instinctual familiarity with their own blood. They know the properties of it so well that they can easily control it.

Other blood can *also* be manipulated but there are so many small things that are *different* that it is difficult to generalise the experience with your own blood to others. On purely biochemical level, the blood of others could have different viscosity, different percentage of different types of cells, different amounts of other trace materials, etc. On metaphysical level, the blood is going to have intrinsically different links.

Learning the more general way of manipulating any blood is very hard. Harder still when trying to apply it for other *vampires*. Knowing how to manipulate the blood of the mortal needs you to *understand* the blood and apply the correct magic force to correctly affect it. However, a *vampire* has stolen the blood of many mortals. It is a big mix. That changes after every feeding. It is much harder to properly understand that blood enough to manipulate it with magic.

Vampires know how to manipulate their own blood but not in a way that they can express to others. The same way you can know how to juggle. Sure, you can do it. You can also *show* somebody how to juggle. However, but you cannot explain to them how to do it. They need to learn themselves. Only with blood manipulation, there is no easy visual shortcut that they can mimic until they actually get the tiny but important details of.

Comment: This is something that I already had in mind, though I could not elaborate it before, thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

## Necromancy is a [fundamental interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_interaction)

Therefore the farther apart two necromantic particles are from each other, the weaker the interaction between them will be.

When people talk about a "life force" they are not joking. There is a fundamental particle, called animon (or pranion or whatever) that makes stuff live. The necron is its antiparticle, and carries death. The actual formula for the necromantic force is this:

$$ F = N\frac{Dd}{r^2} $$

Where $F$ is the total force, $D$ and $d$ are the amount of death/decay in both interacting objects, $r$ is the distance between them, and $N$ is the <strike>emo</strike> necromantic constant, which is 1.764 × 10<sup>−11</sup> m<sup>3</sup>dt<sup>−1</sup>s<sup>−2</sup> (1dt = 1 death unit, about what you get from killing a muskrat).

As you can see, you need an absurd amount of death to get any relevant amount of force over even a few centimeters. Skilled vampires and necromancers can exert much more death with their death muscle, which is why their necromancy can reach further than their own skin.

This is also why vampires can exert influence over their ghouls and familiars over longer distances than they can influence regular people. Those ghouls and familiars have more death into them than a regular person.

Comment: I really like the idea of inserting science into my book, you certainly made it easier, thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

**Vampire blood is a separate entity to the vampire itself**

Call it a kind of magical slime mould or whatever, but the fact could be that the vampire's blood itself is a symbiotic creature that uses the vampire's body to survive and reproduce in exchange for allowing the vampire to be ageless or whatever other benefits your vampires might have.

Controlling blood could be the creature's natural albeit magical ability, and it may even be able to control other vampire blood as well but the reason why it is so darn difficult is because the vampire's blood must overcome the agency of the other vampire's blood's will, essentially enslaving it to its will for a while.

Becoming a vampire would then involve some of this 'blood' introduced to the potential vampire, leading to a relatively painful process where the blood eats the potential vampire's blood to make space for itself in the potential vampire's veins and then eats the vampire's bone marrow to allow it a space to replicate its cells(the bone marrow being where blood cells are normally made anyway for those who don't know). The blood itself eating other blood could also explain why vampires can only survive on blood.

The reason why vampires burn in the sun could also be because of the 'blood', it being photo-volatile enough to even burn up under relatively dim light(moon, fires, stars) outside a body but inside a body it is fine. Lord help the 'blood' if it's ever exposed to sunlight though, it being reactive enough to burn even within the confines of a vampire's veins.

Comment: I loved this, certainly gave me a lot of ideas, I'm considering a fusion between your answer and The Square-Cube Law's, but thanks to both of you, that was very helpful.

Comment: @Vitor-Trevisan just as a further jumping point here - there is a fan theory regarding World of Darkness vampires that the actual "vampire" is the blood inside them. Where the body just happens to be a corpse that acts as a host. It's certainly an interesting perspective to have on vampires. It is a rather unique explanation of why they are immortal and how their powers work. And it leads to the interesting situation where the vampires think they are the corpse body and were human once. Yet are just some very strange liquid derivative of blood that inherited the memories of the host.

Answer (score 0):

**The limitation is entirely mental**

As not-living not-dead things part of a vampire's affliction affects their minds. They can't accept that they should be dead, they're addicted to the idea of life.

Their blood is as disillusioned as they are. When they manipulate their own blood they *think* they're manipulating living blood. A human's living blood is also living, like theirs (so they think), so obviously they should have no issue and they don't have much.

But another vampire's blood, well they become confronted with the truth of the matter. Their own undeath. Such a cognitive dissonance is terribly difficult to deal with. As they magically reach out to the other vampire's blood the idea creeps in, "you died, you're not mortal any more, your soul is forfeit, your skin is pale but you feel fine. people didn't just start liking you because you bought a new coat, it's the vampiric charm..."

Some humans can fool themselves into believing impossibilities their whole life, but if you want to manipulate another vampire's blood you're going to have to face the most difficult-to-accept concept. Their own vampirism. Experienced vampires have already come to grips with this. The more experiences they get the harder the cognitive dissonance is to ignore, and every mind has its breaking point.

Maybe this point of acceptance could be given its own name, like a rite of passage or a sort of transition from vampiric adolescence into adulthood.